# How to use perl to find items from one file and copy contents to new file

Tags: bash, perl

I have been working with a piece of code that a co-worker mentioned worked for him to take a list of text from one file, use the long string from that one file and find said string in another file. When the string is found, it would be copied to a new text file along with its associated data.

There are three files I'm working with:
`ids.txt` has a list of IDs. Each string is prefaced with a `'>'` and contains plain English text and numbers afterwards.

old.txt has a list of these IDs and is in the following (fasta) format:

```
>OLDTEXT_123149 The name of something I need
ASDFISOJTREJASIJAFDSPOJASDFJADPO
AASDFRHSEHGSDGEGRDGSAGSDFGSDFGSD
ASGSDRTGSEDBGDFGSRGREGDFGSDRGDSD
AARTERTERTERYE

>OLDTEXT_1232439 The name of something else I need
ASDFISOJTREJASIJAFDSPOJASDFJADPO
AASDFRHSEHGSDGEGRDGSAGSDFGSDFGSD
ASGSDRTGSEDBGDFGSRGREGDFGSDRGDSD
AARTERTERTERYE
```

What I am trying to do is use the IDs as a way to cross reference the `old.txt`, and take the header and associated data and place it into a new file

I have almost no experience with perl, so I am not sure that I know what the code snippet means. I have tried

```
perl -ne 'if(/^>(\S+)/){$c=$i{$1}}$c?print:chomp;
    $i{$_}=1 if @ARGV' ids.txt old.txt > new.txt
```

Is this the best way to match a header from one text document to another one and then import it to a third document? If it isn't, what would be the best way? If it is, what am I doing wrong with this snippet of code?

Comment: Look into bioperl, which has good support for reading fasta format files.

Comment: Also please provide a sample ids.txt file to go along with that olds.txt one.

Comment: (1) Read `ids.txt` and make each "ID" (what follows `>`?) is a key in a hash (2) Read from `old.txt` in blocks, and in each block extract `>...` line itself and the rest; If ID (from `>` line) is in your hash with IDS then write the rest of the block for its value.  (3) Dump compiled data to a file.  If that's too much data to build up in memory, you can write each component (key+value) as it's found, and delete it from the hash.   That way you'd never have more than all keys + one pop of full data for a key

Answer (score 0):

Your Perl script works, **the problem is the `ids.txt` file**. It should look something like this:

```
OLDTEXT_123149
OLDTEXT_888888
OLDTEXT_777777
OLDTEXT_666666
...
```

Instead of what you described to be the `ids.txt` file contents (lines that start with `>` and have random text after the ID ie `>OLDTEXT_123149 etc etc etc`

Now, cryptic one-liners have given Perl a bad name, so I'm posting a slightly improved version that is **not** modern Perl and strict as it should be, but at least it's more readable, maintains some coherence with your snippet (so that you can understand what it did a little better) **and supports your current `ids.txt` file format** that has lines in the `>[ID] [additional random text]` format:

```
# remember, we're looping line by line through
# each of the @ARGV files ids.txt and old.txt

if ( ( $id ) = /^>(\S+)/ ) {
    # a line that starts with >
    # lets look at the %ids hash to check if we've seen it in ids.txt

    $is_a_match = $ids{ $id };
}

if( @ARGV ) { 
    # is this the ids.txt file? Then save the ID for later retrieval

    $ids{ $id } = 1;
}
elsif( $is_a_match ) {
    # ok, we're in old.txt and there has been a match
    # now print this line from old.txt
    # this is going to print until the next ID comes along

    print;
}
```

Save the above to a file, ie. `fasta.pl` and run it like this:

```
perl -n fasta.pl ids.txt old.txt > new.txt
```